# iTunes submission error

Tags: ios, cordova

I don't know what cause this error when I am uploading the binary to appstore. Do you know what's causing this error?

I'm using phonegap/cordova via xcode to create the app.

[image]

info:

[image]

Comment: Its look like , that your app doesn't contain the icon files that are needed in order to submit the app, please provide the type of icon that are mentioned in the error, and also the URL Scheme you are using is invalid, Correct these errors and resubmit the app.

Comment: You may ignore those missing icon warning. I just submit my app successfully without providing those icons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

Open the **info.plist** file within the application package and edit `URL types->URL Schemes->Item 0 String` from **FB** to **FBxxxxxxxxxx** . x is your facebook app ID. .

Comment: It turns out that my URL Schemes is the facebook app id which is numeric. Can I safely remove this? I no longer use that on my app though. Edited my post with info.list.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. It is uploaded now. You all deserve an upvote.

Answer (score 2):

From Alll Above

```
ERROR ITMS-9000
```

means `URL types->URL Schemes->Facebook App ID`

this with must start with fb means it look like

```
fbYour_Facebook_App_ID
```

Others warnings related to App Icons that you need to solve so add images

1. `120x120` png image for iPhone/iPod required.
2. `76x76` png image for iPad required as your build is for iPad.
3. `152x152` png image for iPad required as your build is for iPad.

Because if you want to target only iOS 7.
 you just need only `76 x 76, 120 x 120 and 152 x 152` icon sizes.

If you also want to target iOS 6, 
you’ll need `57 x 57, 72 x 72, 76 x 76, 114 x 114, 120 x 120, 144 x 144` and `152 x 152` icon sizes.

[image]
And After these modification try as i think it will be successful.

Comment: I have uploaded successfully my app without those necessary icons which show in the warnings. Is it fine? Or I can upload again a new app with the necessary icons?

Comment: So you rejected your build or not as i am just curious  about whether Apple review team will ignore these warning or reject the app.

Answer (score 1):

Your custom URL in the info.plist file starts with numeric. It should start with alphabet. In general reverse domain name is preferable.

Comment: It turns out that my URL Schemes is the facebook app id which is numeric. Can I safely remove this? I no longer use that on my app though.

Answer (score 1):

If your URL Scheme is a Facebook App it should start with

```
fbYOUR_APP_ID_HERE
```

If you no longer use Facebook in your app you can just remove it.

Comment: I've just commented it but maybe I will use it in the future. Does I need to edit this key `<key>FacebookAppID</key> <string>fbYOUR_APP_ID_HERE</string>`